# I get the comma seperator iin excel cell as dot in c#

Tags: c#, excel, hssf

I have got a very strange problem :

for reading  excel I use NPOI nget package and my code is

```
 HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];


          string fileName = file.FileName;
          Stream filestream = file.InputStream;
          string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);

          if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
          {


    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;

     hssfwb= new HSSFWorkbook(filestream);


    ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
    for (int row = 1; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
    {
        if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null) //null is when the row only contains empty cells 
        {
          Cordinates cord = new Cordinates();
            cord.x =sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue;
           cord.y = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(2).ToString();
           cord.h = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(3).ToString();
           lstCordinatestoReturn.Add(cord);

        }
    }
```

SO the strangest thing is that the values in my cells are this 123,233   13,333 
(only digits and comma) and no matter that the cell is formatted as text cell - I always  get the value with dot

```
cord.y = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(2).ToString(); // theresult will ve 123.2333
```

and even the first is giving an exception ()

```
cord.x =sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue; // gives an exception : Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cord.y = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(2).ToString();
```

This is a culture insensitive conversion so will convert the double value to a string with a decimal point.

You need to specify the culture in the `ToString` call to get the required format.